# check for escaped % in JDBC String / VARCHAR comparisons?

Tags: java, sql, regex, jdbc

I am writing a JDBC library that accepts **java.lang.String** objects from user input and emits JDBC **SELECT** statements. I want the presence of unescaped **%** characters to lead the library to use the **LIKE** clause in the comparison whereas for Strings with no unescaped **%** characters the stricter **=** comparison should be used.

E.g. with the following table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE S (V CHARACTER VARYING);
INSERT INTO S (V) VALUES ('%B%'); -- row a
INSERT INTO S (V) VALUES ('%%%'); -- row b
INSERT INTO S (V) VALUES ('%%X'); -- row c
```

I want the string **"\%\%\%"*** (which contains no unescaped **%** characters) to lead to the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM S WHERE V = '%%%'
```

... which will only match 1 row (row b). Whereas the string **"\%%\%"** (which contains one unescaped **%**) should lead to the query:

```
SELECT * FROM S WHERE V LIKE '\%%\%'
```

... which will only match rows a and b (but no c).

Is there a utility class in Java to do that kind of testing for unescaped **%** characters and produce the unescaped versions necessary for the **=** comparison (when all **%** characters are initially escaped?)

The logic should be as follows:

```
 if ( unescapedPercentageExists( s ) )
     likeClause( s )
 else
     equalClause ( removeEscapes( s ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the regex

```
public static boolean unescapedPercentageExists(String s){
    return s.matches(".*((?<=[^\\\\])|^)%.*");
}
```

Test:

```
abc: false
abc\%: false
\%abc: false
a\%bc: false
abc%: true
%abc: true
a%bc: true
```

Comment: it doesn't work for cases involving the escaping the \ character. E.g. the following sequence of strings: %, \%, \\%, \\\%, \\\\% will produce: true, false, false, false, false whereas it should have been: true, false, true, false, true.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't use regular expressions and works with escaped **"\"** characters is the following where I juxtapose the results against the solution of Arun and highlight with **DIFF!** the correct behaviour in the case of strings like **"\\%"**. Sadly, it uses a magic string:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

public class FooMain {

    private static boolean unescapedPercentageExists(String s) {
        return s.matches(".*((?<=[^\\\\])|^)%.*");
    }

    private static String RARE_STRING="use a rare string, @#$645k";

    private static String replacePerc(String s) {
        return s.replace("%", "n"+RARE_STRING);
    }

    private static boolean unescapedPercentageExists2(String s) {
        return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(replacePerc(s)).indexOf("n"+RARE_STRING)!=-1;
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        List<String> testStrs = // read from file to avoid having to escape them as literals (I leave this out as I use one of my utility classes)
        System.out.println("showing if unescaped percentage exists");
        for (String testStr : testStrs) {
            boolean ver1 = unescapedPercentageExists(testStr);
            boolean ver2 = unescapedPercentageExists2(testStr);
            System.out.println(String.format("%10s ver1: %5b ver2: %5b %s",
                                   testStr, ver1, ver2, ver1==ver2?"":"DIFF!"));
        }
    }
}
```

It produces:

```
showing if unescaped percentage exists
       abc ver1: false ver2: false 
     abc\% ver1: false ver2: false 
     \%abc ver1: false ver2: false 
     a\%bc ver1: false ver2: false 
      abc% ver1:  true ver2:  true 
      %abc ver1:  true ver2:  true 
      a%bc ver1:  true ver2:  true 
         % ver1:  true ver2:  true 
        \% ver1: false ver2: false 
       \\% ver1: false ver2:  true DIFF!
      \\\% ver1: false ver2: false 
     \\\\% ver1: false ver2:  true DIFF!
```